# Firebase merge data from different user

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

My application support both anonymous and email login by using Firebase. Users can firstly login by anonymous account, then after that they can continue their work with their new account (using email). I use a feature called `Link Multiple Auth Providers`of Firebase. After "linking" succeeds, user has a new firebase Id which is different from old anonymous Id. This resulted in that all old data has a different path and cannot load in new account(because its path depends on userId).

Is there a way to merge data from anonymous account to the new one?

Comment: When you say 'merge data' what data are your referring to? What would be the path to the 'old data' vs the path to the 'new data'?

Comment: You can't link an existing user to another existing user. However you can link a new user credential to an existing user. The result will have the same uid as the existing user.  If you first sign in anonymously, and then link a facebook credential, the resulting user has the same uid as the original anonymous user. If the facebook credential corresponds to an existing user, then the linking will fail. You will have to merge the data on your own. This depends on the type of database you are using.